# Fix git am -3 conflicts by hand

Tags: git

There are several similar questions but none that concretely adresses this afaik:

I have a git repository whose initial commit adds all files contained in version 1.0 of a project, let's call it `foo`. All following commits add specific modifications to `foo 1.0`. I would now like to port the changes made to a specific subdirectory to another version of, `foo 2.0`. To do this I have first created a patch:

```
 git format-patch --stdout SOME_COMMIT_ID..HEAD -- subdir > subdir.patch
```

Since there have been changes in `foo` between versions `1.0` and `2.0` this patch does not apply cleanly on top of `foo 2.0`. That's fine, I would like to fix any conflicts by hand. But how do I git to actually let me do this? Common advice is to use:

```
git am -3 < subdir.patch
```

Which should perform a three way merge. But all this does is output a bunch of errors of the form:

```
error: patch failed: ...
```

And ultimately:

```
It does not apply to blobs recorded in its index.
Patch failed at 0001 commit SOME_COMMIT_ID
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch=diff' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

That does not help me, why won't git let me fix conflicts by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> git am -3 < subdir.patch
> ```
>
> Which should perform a three way merge.

It should, and it does, under a condition.

> But all this does is output a bunch of errors of the form:
>
> ```
> error: patch failed: ...
> ```
>
> And ultimately:
>
> ```
> It does not apply to blobs recorded in its index.
> Patch failed at 0001 commit SOME_COMMIT_ID
> hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch=diff' to see the failed patch
> When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
> If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
> To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
> ```

I'm not sure what that line `It does not apply to blobs recorded in its index.` above is doing in there, but this indicates that the patch failed either *because* the three-way merge itself failed, in which case `git status` will show some unresolved merge conflicts, *or* because, well, let me quote from [the `git am` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) here:

> `-3`
> `--3way`
> `--no-3way`
>       When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge **if** the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to **and we have those blobs available locally**. `--no-3way` can be used to override am.threeWay configuration variable. For more information, see am.threeWay in [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

(emphasis mine).  The blob information comes from the `index` lines, and your repository *needs to have those blobs* in it for `-3` to do anything useful here.  If you don't have a blob with the specified hash ID, you'll just have to hand-apply the entire patch: consider using `git apply --reject` and hand-editing.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks, I didn't know about `git apply --reject`, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Peter: I'll add a note from personal experience: using `--reject` is painful. :-) With luck you will have just a few `.rej` files.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, fixing it "by hand" is *exactly* what git is asking you to do in this situation. Not always the best recourse, but worked well in my use case, which was that the SHAs for commits weren't, for some reason, matching up from one workstation to the other (which is what I believe it's telling us with "*It does not apply to blobs recorded in its index*") even though the contents and line numbers were a perfect match between the patch file and the code.

That means after you see...

```
Patch failed at 0001 [Whatever the comment for your commit was]
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
```

... you can open that file -- `.git/rebase-apply/patch` -- and apply those changes *however you want*.

Once you're done, you need to stage those changes like you normally would with some flavor of...

```
git add [something]
```

Once that's done and you have all the changes required to match what you expected to happen in that patch-commit, **instead** of committing, you continue following the instructions in the warning message and enter...

```
git am --continue
```

The information for that patch commit (original date, commit message, etc) will be entered against the changes you staged. The `.git/rebase-apply/patch` file will be deleted (ensure you don't have a `.swp` file or other artifact in there preventing cleanup), and `git am` will move on to the next commit in the patch.

Decent chance, I'd bet, you run into the same issue with other commits with your patch, *but for those where you don't, you're in business!* Any commits `git am` *can* patch in it will before asking you to resolve things by hand again.

So if you don't mind some elbow grease, solving by hand is precisely the situation `git am` has dumped us into, very nicely one commit from the patch file at a time, and only those it can't figure out on its own.